# Ansible: Using different encrypted passwords for hosts in the same group

Tags: encryption, ansible

This seems like a very easy thing to me but I cannot get it to work.

**The Problem:**

I have several groups in my inventory that have hosts with different passwords in them and I want the passwords encrypted via Vault. For one group that has only one host in it, I encrypted the password string, named it "ansible_password" and put it into group_vars/groupName.yml. It gets recognized automatically and works fine but how would I add another encrypted password for another host in that group, naming it ansible_password again to have it automatically recognized wont work. So how to assign an encrypted password to one specific host and not a group.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add host specific vaults like so:

```yaml
# group_vars/all/vars.yml
ansible_password: "{{ vaul_ansible_password }}"
```

```yaml
# host_vars/host1/vault.yml (decrypted)
vault_ansible_password: "secret123"
```

```yaml
# host_vars/host2/vault.yml (decrypted)
vault_ansible_password: "123secret"
```

Comment: Big thanks, that worked great for me. Actually didn't know about the possibility of a host_vars folder.